# Weeding out the OOM and consecutive mysqld crash

Tags: mysql, outofmemoryerror

I am trying to weed out the out of memory issue that seems to be hitting `mysqld` service. The service dies totally randomly - sometimes once a week, sometimes every two days.

My VPS has 6GB of RAM and no swap file (my provider does not allow/support swaps). My application is `PHP`-based (`Symfony` framework) and runs on `Apache 2.2`.

This evening I observed a RAM usage spike. Regrettably, I was not able to capture an exact output of `free -m`, but I remeber that `-/+ buffers/cache` for column `free` was around 1G. The RAM usage was going up and down from 4.8G to 5.2G.

During the maintenance window, I shut down `httpd`, `mysqld` and `mongod`, after which I've got the following `free -m` output:

```
[root@XXXYYYZZZ ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          6144       4916       1227          0          0       1207
-/+ buffers/cache:       3709       2434
Swap:            0          0          0
```

My question is what going on with those `3709M` of used memory? The `top` command does not reveal much:

```
top - 19:54:58 up 3 days,  6:35,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks:  21 total,   1 running,  20 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   6291456k total,  5034692k used,  1256764k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  1236060k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
    1 root      20   0 19236 1180  932 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 init
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd/23992
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper/23992
  140 root      16  -4 10644  520  248 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 udevd
  482 root      20   0  179m 1252  828 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.04 rsyslogd
  493 dbus      20   0 21408  616  376 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 dbus-daemon
  510 root      20   0 66632 1232  520 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sshd
  517 root      20   0 22184  904  668 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xinetd
  870 root      20   0 66828  924  276 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 saslauthd
  871 root      20   0 66828  680   32 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 saslauthd
  886 root      20   0 83080 2664  840 S  0.0  0.0   0:04.99 sendmail
  894 smmsp     20   0 78668 2108  648 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 sendmail
  944 root      20   0  114m 1232  628 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.81 crond
  955 root      20   0 88304  21m 1784 S  0.0  0.3   0:05.25 miniserv.pl
22840 root      20   0 96276 4448 3460 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.09 sshd
22842 root      20   0  105m 1988 1524 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.03 bash
22985 root      20   0 96300 4168 3164 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 sshd
22987 root      20   0 57848 2340 1624 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.04 sftp-server
23313 root      20   0 96276 4472 3460 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.68 sshd
23315 root      19  -1  105m 2024 1544 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.16 bash
25080 root      19  -1 14900 1220  992 R  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 top
```

I am aware that Linux does the caching in RAM, but I would say this is pretty irregular. I might be wrong and, as a matter of fact, I hope I am.

After carefully reading through the `drop_cache` call which I could execute to, well, drop the cache, I decided to try going with that, only to get this:

```
[root@XXXYYYZZZ ~]# sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
-bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
```

So, I am not able to drop the caches, am not able to create a swap file and I am flying pretty close to the sun with RAM consumption (and I have earned a few burns due to `mysqld` crashes).

Does anyone know how to investigate this better?

If I am going to topple down on my VPS provider, with which I am getting pretty much annoyed recently, I need solid proof that I am not misinterpreting performance data, or worse, that legitimate process is in fact consuming that much RAM.

Thanks a lot!

### Update

I ran the `virt-what` and got `openvz`

### Update2: OOM entries from messages:

```
/var/log/messages-20161009:Oct  2 16:43:43 XXXYYYZZZ kernel: [56050139.271683] Out of memory in UB 23992: OOM killed process 22029 (mysqld) score 0 vm:5044284kB, rss:656944kB, swap:8280kB
/var/log/messages-20161009:Oct  2 16:43:55 XXXYYYZZZ kernel: [56050150.552528] Out of memory in UB 23992: OOM killed process 30486 (mysqld) score 0 vm:310088kB, rss:214456kB, swap:0kB
/var/log/messages-20161009:Oct  5 12:56:17 XXXYYYZZZ kernel: [56295842.893210] Out of memory in UB 23992: OOM killed process 13284 (mysqld) score 0 vm:5066092kB, rss:694760kB, swap:40kB
/var/log/messages-20161023:Oct 22 17:54:09 XXXYYYZZZ kernel: [1219419.032263] Out of memory in UB 23992: OOM killed process 789 (mysqld) score 0 vm:5057832kB, rss:698980kB, swap:0kB
/var/log/messages-20161023:Oct 22 17:54:20 XXXYYYZZZ kernel: [1219428.340161] Out of memory in UB 23992: OOM killed process 21700 (mysqld) score 0 vm:310088kB, rss:271892kB, swap:0kB
/var/log/messages-20161030:Oct 29 12:14:47 XXXYYYZZZ kernel: [1804212.497098] Out of memory in UB 23992: OOM killed process 25691 (mysqld) score 0 vm:5057548kB, rss:690164kB, swap:0kB
/var/log/messages-20161030:Oct 29 12:15:06 XXXYYYZZZ kernel: [1804222.381820] Out of memory in UB 23992: OOM killed process 23659 (mysqld) score 0 vm:310088kB, rss:248376kB, swap:0kB
```

Comment: Is this provider by any chance using openvz? As far as I remember those VPS providers that use OpenVZ won't allow swap. I was running into very similar issue about 8 years ago, once every couple of weeks our container was running out of ram and crashing. After going nowhere with the provider support - we switched to a different provider which was using xen based virtualization at the time and never had same issue.

Comment: @DmitryZayats: Yes, indeed, it is `openvz`. I am also considering migration to some other VPS provider.

Comment: I think it's time to stop considering and start migrating. This provider has most likely oversubscribed the host RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, unless you are doing some testing *you* should never need to drop the caches. The Linux kernel uses 'free' memory for caches. If something requests memory and it's not available elsewhere the request will be satisfied from the cache memory.

To start to solve your problem you should look in your logs. They should contain information from the OOM system about why it has come uot to play and what it has done.

As others have suggested, it seems like you may be using a container VPS (openvz etc). If this is the case they it is likely that your only real solution is to move to a different VPS that uses a different virtualisation technology e.g. KVM etc.

Comment: I could not agree more about not having to touch the cache. After all, it starts caching right afterwards. Besides, if I would for example run it via cron, I would feel like I doing everything backwards. As for the container, you are dead right - it is `openvz`. I went back to logs and saw basically nothing more that those OOM messages I posted above...

Answer (score 0):

Error that you got

```
[root@XXXYYYZZZ ~]# sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
-bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
```

Is the result of noclobber enabled (man bash and search for >| ). Try it like this

```
sync; echo 3 >| /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

And by the way - you can try to start from this

```
sync; echo 2 >| /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

You can also see output of slabtop command to see what's eating your ram. Not that it will help much, but you at least will be aware if it's coming from some slab cache or not.
Also install sysstat package and enable sar with 1 minute resolution, so you can analyze your system performance historically instead of monitoring online in real time.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry! I am going to try this in 2-3 hours during the maintenance window. And, definitely, I need `sysstat` in order to get a glimpse of historical data not the current one.

Comment: Interestingly enough, `slabtop` does not work with a message: `fopen /proc/slabinfo: No such file or directory`

Comment: This plainly has nothing to do with noclobber, and slabtop won't be available on this system.

Comment: @Dmitry: I have put in place tracking of CPU+RAM via `sysstat` almost two hours ago and have set up a cron to do it every minute. I am going to take a look on the data later and inspect it for some clues. Currently, the RAM consumption is stable with just over `3GB` being used, but as we all agree, I am probably going to move to other provider - I just cannot gamble with to twitchy RAM :)